# iOS migrating users from parse to firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are migrating an iOS app from parse to firebase.

In the firebase migrate from parse [document](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios) it says under "migrate account":

> Use an authentication server to create a custom token, a JSON Web Token (JWT) signed with your service account's private key; in the custom token, set the value of the `uid` claim to the value that you're using on Parse to identify the user (most likely the PFUser objectId).

Is this necessary? is this only to have a proper objectId as uid? we don't have an authentication server and couldn't find Obj-c examples for it.

what will be the easiest way to migrate users?